# C++ extern variable why can't I define it in main

Tags: c++

use.cpp

```
#include "my.h"

int main()
{
    int foo = 7;
    
    print_foo();
    print(99);
}
```

my.h

```
#pragma once
extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print(int i);
```

my.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "my.h"

void print_foo()
{
    std::cout << foo;
}

void print(int i)
{
    std::cout << i;
}
```

So my question is pretty simple I declare an extern int foo in the header file then I DEFINE foo in main, why does this not work? If I don't define foo in main and define it outside of main in use.cpp then it works but when I define it in main() it doesn't. Why?

Comment: The definition in `main()` is local to that function, hence it can't serve as definition for a global variable as defined wit `extern`.

Comment: So basically it needs like some global defintion because of the extern? When I define it in main like that main just thinks its some new variable called foo?

Answer (score 3):

At global scope, the declaration

```
extern int foo;
```

declares a variable named `foo` that has *external linkage*, meaning that it might be defined in another translation unit.

At *block scope* (*i.e.*, as a statement in the body of a function), the definition

```
int foo = 7;
```

has *no linkage*. That means that the compiler will never consider *this* `foo` to be the same entity as another `foo` from another scope. Therefore, this simply creates another variable that's unrelated to the global one, and does not initialize the global one.

Comment: So basically the linker sees that extern in the global scope and goes oh okay I'm gonna look for a definition of a global variable named foo? Because the extern variable was defined in the global scope too? And also it seems like extern variables are only really useful when global? Because I mean when else would you be able to declare an extern variable somewhere and then also define it without making a new variable?

Comment: @jaronbass21 It's actually simpler than that: the linker does not emit a symbol for the local `foo` at all, because it has no linkage. So there is nothing for the global `extern` declaration to link with. `extern` generally is only used at namespace scope (including global scope). It is possible to use it at local scope, but this is confusing and should be avoided.

Comment: Well now I also have a tiny question about linking I'm kinda confused about that say I have the local foo in main and I also defined foo outside of main my question is after all these cpp files are turned into object files what exactly is the linking doing? I mean it's not just copying and pasting all the code into one file is it fair to say that the linker just links every function declaration with a definition? But then what exactly happens with the local foo variable? It doesn't really need to be linked with anything but how does all this turn into one file?

Comment: @jaronbass21 each source file is converted into object code by the compiler then the linker link all the object code file into one executable file( it checks the definition of function or variable defined somewhere else i.e other translation unit or library).

Comment: @jaronbass21 The linker is responsible for linking together definitions with external linkage with declarations of such entities in other translation units. In some cases, it's responsible for deduplicating entities that are multiply defined (e.g. inline functions). Finally, it also must link the user code together with the language runtime, and add appropriate headers to conform to the binary executable format of the target platform.

Comment: Okay but say I have just one variable defined or one function defined in just one file, does it basically just kinda drop that function definition in there? Like that function is just defined in one file but now when I'm linking everything can I just say the function kinda gets dropped into that executable idk how to explain it

Comment: Also wow I'm annoying sorry but one last question well technically if the linker just links everything say I have a function foo() defined in main.cpp and I wanna use that foo() in a file called main2.cpp well why can't I just link these two files and use foo() in main2.cpp? Why does main2.cpp need a header file that declares that foo() exists? Can't the linker just say hey main.cpp defined this function that you wanna use so here you go

Comment: @jaronbass21 Questions about how the linker works are separate from the original post, and should be posted as separate questions, not comments.